# Are there any special challenges with non-trophy incentives?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I recall in Dark Souls 2 there being special rings granted to the player for beating a play through without dying and also beating the game without using a bonfire. The map of flames in Majula would also turn blue if an area were beaten eight times. Are there any incentives like these in Dark Souls 3 to do challenging feats? I'm especially curious due to the Estus Flask's item description saying "no journey of import has been made without an Estus Flask."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any for now. DLCs might change that but there's no information out about that as far as I know. I'll update this answer if it changes.

- Getting all the rings, spells, weapons, ect require at least 3 playthroughs, but there's no other special requirements. Assuming Steam achievements are correct, that indicates there's no hidden/secret items.
- There's no way out of the various secret areas beside bonfires or using an item (which counts as using the bonfire you teleport to as far as I can tell).
- People have done no death runs and haven't gotten anything.
- You cannot respawn bosses.
- The game files have been datamined and no such thing have been found.
- Dark Souls item descriptions have always been vague lore dumps; the previous flasks descriptions says similar stuff.

The **Ashes of Ariandel** DLC is now out. There is still no special challenges as far as I know, but there are two noteworthy secrets.

- > If you return to the friendly Corvian Settler NPC after clearing the DLC, he will give you a Titanite Slab.
- > If you followed the "Lord of Hollows" questline and speak to Yuria with Sister Friede's soul in your inventory, she will have something new to say.

The **Ringed City** DLC has been out for a while now and still no special challenges have been found. Noteworthy stuff:

- > After killing the last boss, you can return to the painter girl in the Ariandel Chapel for some new dialog.
- > After killing the last boss, you can take a right from the boss door to find the ruins of a church. Shira will spawn and attack you. Defeating her will give you her weapon, and her armor can be found in the now-open room where she would talk to you.
- > In the last boss area, follow the left wall to find a lone wandering ringed knight with dual greatswords. He drops a titanite slab the first time you kill him.

Comment: I already upvoted and accepted the answer before either DLC came out, but I doubly appreciate you checking back and editing with little secrets about the DLC!

Comment: The "Unkindled Ending" has no achievement attached, but I wouldn't really say that's any kind of "challenge".